# logging request urls in django

Tags: python, django, logging

From advanced logging, I am able to get debug level logs for database calls, but cannot figure out how to get request URLs logged.

```
    # Log Django URL requests
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': False,
        'level': 'WARNING',
    },
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/ was not too helpful here. Is logging URL requests for debugging even supported?

Comment: Please clarify, are the url requests showing up in the console?

Comment: Nothing showing in the console for URLs. I can get database logging working in console by changing django level to DEBUG, but still no requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick [search](https://github.com/django/django/search?p=2&q=%22django.request%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for logging in Django source suggests there is no logging of URL hits.

The `django.request` logger seems to be used only when there are errors (500) or warnings (404, etc).

You can use a [custom middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4839713/1268926) that logs all request URLs.

Comment: This is correct but there's a new logger: `django.server` that can be used.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-server

Answer (score 4):

While the current accepted answer is correct about `django.request`, there have been some updates:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-server

`django.server` (added in Django 1.10) logger logs all requests when log level is INFO.

(note: only works with manage.py runserver - but you shouldn't be using Django log requests in production anyway; there's nginx or similar for that.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have defined `console` in `handlers`. If so, do check that you have set the appropriate `level` of `DEBUG` there. By default, it is set to `INFO`.

Comment: 'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },